# Webapp address different from .war file name

Tags: java, windows, web-applications, war

somehow I dont get this thing with the correct webaddress if calling a deployed webapp.
If I create my .WAR files in Eclipse - the webadress to get access to this webapp is always the name of the .WAR file.

As example, if my file name is `myapp.war` I can use something like `http://adress:9999/myapp`
Now I see some other webapps, the warfile name and url are different. What if the webapp is deployed but you dont know the name of the webapp, because it´s different from the .war file name?

Comment: which web server are u using?

Comment: web app name have nothing with context path. Usually by default application servers deploy web app to the context of web app name but not necessarily. You always can specify on which context you want to deploy. For example in tomcat there is management app that you can use to see on which context certain web app is deployed

Comment: @Juned Ahsan: as I know its a webshere webserver. So in this case it not possible to see the name in the war file?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question,

```
What if the webapp is deployed but you dont know the name of the webapp, 
because it´s different from the .war file name?
```

You won't be able to find the WAR. As simple as that.

Nothing to do with your question , but let me elaborate on how this happens. Take for e.g. a web application that uses Maven for dependency management.

There is a tag in maven, that can be specified to set final name of the application that can be used to access the application.

`pom.xml`

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>testWar</artifactId>
<name>testWar</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

This piece of code tells maven to build the application as `testWar.war`.

Now, you can specify how you want to access the application if you set:

```
<finalName>mycontextpath</finalName>
```

Then your finalName is being used for 'deployment' and you may access your webapp via

`http://localhost:8080/mycontextpath/`

By default, almost all webserver use `artifactID` as the deployment path but you can specify to use the `finalName` like for e.g when using `Jetty` plugin :

```
<plugin> 
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId> 
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<configuration>   
<contextPath>${build.finalName}</contextPath>      
</configuration>             
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

And if you want manually link webapp folder to, say Tomcat you can do this. I use this method to run webapps directly from the project development folder. Easy to change or run multiple versions concurrently, editing jsp+html+js files can immediately be refreshed in browser. Production deployment is mywebapp.war packaging and uploaded to j2ee server.

**tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:/projects/mywebapp/web_v3.1"
   reloadable="true" crossContext="true" >
</Context>
```

And browse to address `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/`

Or give path attribute in context.xml file, you may use docBase and path in a same file.

**tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:/projects/myapp2/web" path="/myapp"
   reloadable="true" crossContext="true" >
</Context>
```

And browse to address `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`

Answer (score 1):

That path is called 'context path', it doesn't depend on your war file name.

Basically while deploying the web application on web sphere, you would come across a screen which shows 'Context Root'. You should give whatever name you like, mostly application name. Now this becomes the path of your web application access. e.g. If you give '*stocktrade*' as context root then you can access `http://localhost/stocktrade/index.html`.

In case of weblogic server, you can define weblogic.xml parallel to web.xml. This file should define context root of your application.

For JBOSS server, jboss.xml is avaialble. You can search on Internet for the respective files.